# How to mock class method called inside another class in pytest?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to test a class, which also relies on method of another class:

```
current target class (C1) --> calls another class (C2) --> calls method from another class (C3)
```

My problem is, how can I mock the method from C3?
Here is a sample code:

```
class C1:
   def __init__(self, key, config):
      self.my_c2 = C2()
      ...

class C2: 
   def __init__(self):
      my_c3 = C3()
      my_source = my_c3.get_source_info()
      self.dimension = my_source["dimensions"]  # this method needs to connect to remote server

   def is_satisfied():   
      return True if self.dimension["width"] > 100 else False
```

My goal is to test `C1` using dummy input values. However, as it needs to connect to remote server which is currently unavailable, I need to mock up the `C3.get_dimension()` method as well.

Currently, I used the following code for that:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_config(mocker):
   my_mocker = mocker.patch("root.modules.Class3.get_source_info")
   my_mocker["dimensions"] = {"width": 150, "height": 100}

   my_input = {"key": "my_key", "type": "my_test"}
   return my_input


@pytest.fixture
def test_my_class(my_config):
   return C1(key="random_test", config=my_config)
```

However, it throws out the following error:

```
root:c2.py:11 An exception occurred in C2::is_satisfied()'>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'MagicMock'
```

And it still tries to connect to remote server:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 535, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 8083)
```

What did I miss here?